# How do I use gsub to search and replace using a regex?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, gsub

I want to filter tags out of a description string, and want to make them into anchor tags. I am not able to return the value of the tag.

My input is:

```
a = "this is a sample #tag and the string is having a #second tag too"
```

My output should be:

```
a = "this is a sample <a href="/tags/tag">#tag</a> and the string is having a <a href="/tags/second">#second</a> tag too"
```

So far I am able to do some minor stuff but I am not able to achive the final output. This pattern:

```
a.gsub(/#\S+/i, "<a href='/tags/\0'>\0</a>")
```

returns:

```
"this is a sample <a href='/tags/\u0000'>\u0000</a> and the string is having a <a href='/tags/\u0000'>\u0000</a> tag too"
```

What do I need to do differently?

Comment: You can take a bit of help using `nokogiri`.

Comment: @Priti just for this small thing I don't want add a gem in my application

Comment: If this was HTML parsing, then Nokogiri would be of use. It's HTML generation which reduces Nokogiri's value significantly for this purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
a.gsub(/#(\S+)/, '<a href="/tags/\1">\0</a>')
```

The reason why your replacement doesn't work is that you must use **double escape** when you are between double quotes:

```
a.gsub(/#(\S+)/, "<a href='/tags/\\1'>\\0</a>")
```

Note that the `/i` modifier is not needed here.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the `/i` isn't needed. The reason is that there is no lower-case value for `'#'` and everything following it is matched by `\S+` anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You need to give `gsub` a block if you want to do something with the match from the regex:

```
a.gsub(/#(\S+)/i) { "<a href='/tags/#{$1}'>##{$1}</a>" }
```

`$1` is a global variable that Ruby automatically fills with the first capture block in the matched string.

Comment: As evidenced by the other answers, it's possible to use `\1` to reference the capture without a block being passed to `gsub`. So, while the answer works, the assertion isn't quite correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a.gsub(/(?<a>#\w+)/, '<a href="/tags/\k<a>">\k<a></a>')
```

Comment: returns `"this is a sample <a href=\"/tags/#tag\">#tag</a> and the string is having a <a href=\"/tags/#second\">#second</a> tag too"` (`href` is not as specified in the question)

Comment: I don't think this answer deserved a down vote just because of that small error.

Comment: I agree, it was the principle of using named capture groups that was the key point.

Comment: Stylistically, I'd probably use a longer capture name than `a`. It blends into the pattern's use of `<a href...` and `</a>`, causing some consternation when reading it. I'd use something like `?<tagval>` to make it stand out.

Comment: @DaveSexton: +1 I didn't know that using named captures in a replacement pattern was possible